# How a run() method is called when we extend Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

While going through the source code of `java.lang.Thread` class. Curiously I wanted to see how a `run()` method (user defined run()) is called by Thread class. when I am implementing `Runnable` interface as below

```
Thread waiterThread = new Thread(waiter, "waiterThread");
waiterThread.start();
```

In the above code from `Thread` class's constructor `init()` method is being called and from there itself they initialized the `Runnable` instance as `this.target = target`.

from `start()` method they are calling a `native` method `start0()` which may in-turn call `run()` method of the `Thread` class which causes user defined `run()` method to execute.

the following is the `run()` method implementation from Thread class:

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

My question is when we extend `java.lang.Thread` class and when we call `start()` method as below.

```
public class HelloThread extends Thread {

  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
      (new HelloThread()).start();
   }

 }
```

`target = null` in the above case so is it the native method's (`start0()`) responsibility to set target=HelloThread's instance ? and how does a `run()` method of mine is called in case when I extend `Thread` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does a run() method of mine is called in case when I extend Thread class

Because you extended the class.  You overrode the run() method to do something different. The @Override annotation is used to highlight that this method overrides a parent method.

The `target` doesn't get magically changed, you ignored in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
new HelloThread()
```

itself will call the `init()` method which will set your target. It will be set to null in case you are extending Thread class. So target will be null.

If you see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) for run() method it clearly says

**If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.Subclasses of Thread should override this method.**

Answer (score 0):

In start() method-  underlying runtime object run() method is going to get called within start() method. And here underlying runtime object is  HelloThread class object. Thats why run() method of HelloThread is called.